# Running Total with Slicer from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a running total dax measure that works. Problem now is that the slicer on the page is coming from another data set which is linked to the source table of running total data set and when you select the slicer it doesn't filter anything.

```
Homes Connected = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( refv_FTTH_HomesConnected[ActualHomesConnected] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( refv_FTTH_HomesConnected ), refv_FTTH_HomesConnected[Month_sort2] <= MAX ( refv_FTTH_HomesConnected[Month_sort2] ) )
)
```

Is there a way to incorporate the columns from the other dataset to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ALL` in your `FILTER` removes any slicer selection filtering.

Try using `ALLSELECTED` instead.